# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'as_widget'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to have more control of my Django forms by adding a custom filter

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='addclass')
def addclass(value, arg):
    return value.as_widget(attrs={'class': arg})
```

but getting the `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'as_widget'`  error

here is my view

```
def index(request):
   notes = Note.objects.all()
   form = NoteForm()
   if request.method == 'POST':
     form = NoteForm(request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return redirect('keep:index')
context = {'notes':notes, 'form':form}
return render(request,'Keep/note_form.html',context)

def update(request,id):
    notes = Note.objects.get(id=id)
    form = NoteForm(instance=notes)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NoteForm(request.POST, instance=notes)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('keep:index')
    context = {'notes': notes, 'form': form}
    return render(request,"Keep/update.html",context)


def delete(request,id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Note,id=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        obj.delete()
        return redirect('keep:index')
    return render(request,"Keep/delete.html")
```

PS. Before you throw me links to other similar questions, i want you to know i checked pretty much all the links and none of the solutions worked for me.
Most common is this:

```
else:
   form = UserForm()
return render(request, 'register_user.html', {'form': form})
```

but as you can see, i did exact same thing but that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

In my case (I was struggled by the same error: `'CommentForm' object has no attribute 'as_widget'`) I was using  a pipe with some function of `widget_tweaks` library on CommentForm, which doesn't work.

Try to look for unused libraries but imported in **INSTALLED_APPS**(***settings.py***); you also can check your HTML5 file for unused `{% load some_library %}`; If nothing wrong with what is said above, try to check for ***Django Template Tags*** incorrect syntax
(in my case it was `{{comment_form|add_class:"form-control" }}`)

I hope it would help you!